# How to publish data(Uplink Measures) supports MQTT protocol with Mosquitto publisher client to The Things Network(TTN) as broker

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, iot, fiware, lorawan

Problem: I am unable to publish uplink measures to TTN(The Things Network,MQTT Broker) through MQTT Publisher Client. Follow these steps...

1. Installed Eclipse Mosquitto providers a CLI to subscribe and to publish 
   messages.
2. Start Mosquitto Service.
   `start mosquitto service`
3. MQTT command to publish uplink measure:

   ```
   mosquitto_pub -h eu.thethings.network -p 1883 -u applicationid-P ttn-account-v2.xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -t applicationid/devices/deviceid/up -m '{"port":1,"payload_raw":"AWcAuw=="}' -d
   ```
4. MQTT command to subscribe uplink measure:

   ```
   mosquitto_sub -h eu.thethings.network -p 1883 -u applicationid -P ttn-account-v2.x2Q20I2hDo1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -t applicationid/devices/deviceid/up
   ```

Comment: Why are you planning to run a DoS attack on TTN's broker?

Comment: I have no intentions to run a DoS attack on TTN's broker. I want to send uplink request to TTN's broker using MQTT publisher client. I have updated my question  accordingly.

Comment: That's not what the original question asked, you were asking how to use JMeter to load test somebody else's infrastructure, that sounds very much like a DoS

Comment: Yes, You are right earlier question sounds like a Dos that's why after your comment i  updated my question so that it is easy to understand.

Comment: Since you have now substantially changed the scope of the question I suggest you delete this one and re-ask it

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you can really reach to this `52.169.76.255` host and `1883` port using [telnet](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) tool or equivalent, for example I cannot connect to this server.

According to [WHOIS information](https://dnschecker.org/ip-whois-lookup.php) the IP address belongs to Microsoft corporation so my expectation is that you're trying to test an application which is deployed in [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) cloud infrastructure. I would recommend checking if port `1883` is [open for incoming connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) and if not you will need to configure the VM and open the port (you might also need to do the same in the OS [firewall](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(networking)))

Once you will be able to establish the connection using telnet (or equivalent) JMeter should also be able to connect and send/receive the messages.

Just in case check out [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide/)

Comment: I have no intentions to run a DoS attack on TTN's broker. I want to send uplink request to TTN's broker using MQTT publisher client. I have updated my question accordingly.